# symfony querybuilder for search by relation in collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-query

I have Entity Application with relation to Applicant

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Applicant::class, inversedBy="applications")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $applicant;
```

now I try create QueryBuilder for search application by Applicant name in ApplicantRepository i have

```
    public function searchByName($searchString)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.name LIKE :phrase')->setParameter('phrase', '%'.$searchString.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

in controller I have

```
$applicants = $applicantRepository->searchByName($searchString);
```

Now I want search Application with applicant name in this applicants collection. May I use QueryBuilder fot that?

I am trying something like this

```
public function getApprovedSearchByApplicants($applicants)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.applicant IN (:applicants)')
            ->setParameter('applicants', $applicants)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Application::$applicant` === `Applicant::$name`?

Comment: Try to add `referencedColumnName="name"` to `@JoinColumn()` annotation

Comment: I try in search all application which have applicants name with searching text

Comment: Also, if you searching the Application - you need to use ApplicationRepository, not ApplicantRepository and just search like `$appRepo->findBy(['applicant' => $applicantEntity->getId()])`, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes you are right, but my $applicant maybe collection of $applicant

Comment: One Application can have many Applicants?

Comment: So, anyway, `findBy()` will return a collection of the found entities by criteria.

Comment: I add to question some code to view what I am trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222680/discussion-between-eugene-ruban-and-mardon).

Answer (score 1):

so, looking to your configuration, your `Application::$applicant` === `Applicant::$name`, just because `Application::$applicant` property has `Applicant::$id` value, by default. You can check the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional).

So, this way, you need to make smth like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Applicant::class, inversedBy="applications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="applicant_name", referencedColumnName="name", nullable=false)
 */
private $applicant;
```

It should work.

**UPDATE after question update and discussions:**

So, the problem was in the testing data in the database. Bad question.

Comment: Yes, I continued in answers then, I found that you used wrong repository, to get Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Search by search string:

```
$entityManager
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT ct
        FROM App\Entity\Application ct
            JOIN ct.applicant nt
        WHERE nt.name LIKE :phrase
    ')
    ->setParameters(['phrase' => "%$searchString%"])
    ->getResult();
```

Search by applicants:

```
$entityManager
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT ct
        FROM App\Entity\Application ct
            JOIN ct.applicant nt
        WHERE nt IN (:nts)
    ')
    ->setParameters(['nts' => $applicants])
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it, but something like the following code should do the trick. It is almost the same solution as goulashsoup proposed, but without typing raw DQL.

```php
/**
 * @param array|Applicant[] $applicants
 *
 * @return array|Application[]
 */
public function findByApplicants(array $applicants): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')

    return $qb->innerJoin('a.applicant', 'at')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->in('at.id', ':applicants')
        )
        ->setParameter('applicants', $applicants)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

I don't think you need to name the function wtih "ApprovedSearch" since the method is only aware of a list of Applicant for whom you want the list of Application.